# Can I set a limit on attempt number of ssh authentication passphrase?

Tags: ssh-keys

I recently changed to ssh-key from password for security.

But ssh-key can also be compromised when the private key file is somehow stolen.

So I set a passphrase on the private key.

But it seems that I can try as many as I wish.

So is there any way I can set a limit on how many one can try passphrase?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but if you chose a secure passphrase it would be very hard (read: impossible) to brute force. Think 'as9h8J)F(DS*(dsh*' and not 'monkey123'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't.

The passphrase is used to add a layer of encryption to the key. The process is completely offline, and the methods employed are well known, as the software is open source. It's basically a function taking the key and passphrase as input, and returning unencrypted key.

As it's completely offline there's no meaningful way to limit the number of attempts.

Comment: Well understood. Is there any other way to put another security layer? maybe something in ~/.bashrc that runs automatically after ssh-login is sucessful might do unless there is a way to break out of it, for example pressing CTRL+C

Comment: You could store the key on a smart card so that noone can copy it. https://developers.yubico.com/PGP/SSH_authentication/

Comment: @KHKim You can also combine multiple authentications at once. For example key AND standard password (some information in `man sshd_config` at the AuthenticationMethods entry).

Comment: @A.B Thank you for the tip. You made my day.